# bootstrap-sass images not showing, or how to override a Gem path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

Been struggling with this for the past 3 days to no avail.

In my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '3.1.5' # there is a problem with 3.1.6 and we need to downgrade until they update it.
gem "bootstrap-sass"
```

Bootstrap CSS works fine but it will not show the images in Development or Production mode.

The development.log has this to say about the GET error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/railsAdminApi/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see, it is using the project name as part of the path when it shouldn't.

In my `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` file I have this:

```
$iconSpritePath: asset-url("glyphicons-halflings.png", image) !default;
$iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-url('glyphicons-halflings-white.png', image);
```

Note that I use `asset-url` instead of `image-path` as per this [github discussion](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/105).

In any case, it doesn't matter what I put into this variable (or even if I change it back to `image-path`) the route will always stay the same, I cannot change it no matter what I try.

If I edit the gem file's vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_sprites.css.scss file directly (which is a horrible thing to do of course) and put in `'assets/'` instead of the Sass variable, the browser stops complaining about not finding the icon but still no image will be shown.

It gets trickier:

Putting the Sass variables back into _sprites.css.scss and precompiling shows the images in Production mode on my local machine (but not Development mode). However, on the remote server no combination will show the images in Production mode.

So, looking for any help or perhaps a way to uninstall everything related to bootstrap (clean things up might be an option since I did play around with other bootstrap gems that I subsequently uninstalled on the local machine).

Thanks.

**Edit**

Long story short, I had to remove RVM and install rbenv for my gems to work again. This time I went with `twitter-bootstrap-rails` which worked better, less javascript errors but I still have the same problem with the images, both for the glyphs and the fontawesome fonts.

It seems that no matter what I put into the variables (this time it is respecting them) it always pre-pends the project path `railsAdminApi` to the path.

In desperation I thought I could add a path in my `routes.rb` file so that the path it's looking for is accessible, something like:

```
get 'railsAdminApi' => 'public/'
```

Of course Rails complains there is no public controller, but I don't know of a way to create static routes without a controller. I even tried creating a softlink but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Can you post an example from a view where you are using the sprite?

Comment: @PaulSimpson, not sure if this is what you mean: `<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=game SNES The+Legend+of+Zelda%3A+A+Link+to+the+Past" class="btn" target="_blank"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>`

Comment: So you are overriding those variables because with the default values no images show? What version of rails so I can try and reproduce? It's working fine for me using `rails 3.2.3`, `bootstrap-sass 2.0.1` and `sass-rails 3.2.3`.

Comment: Even without overriding the variables they won't show. I assume we're talking about the $iconSpritePath variables. `Rails 3.1.1`. `sass-rails 3.1.5` since 3.1.6 had an issue with precompile errors (how are you using 3.2.3?) `bootstrap-sass 2.0.2`

Comment: Just used a blank gemset, installed `rails 3.1.1`, `bootstrap-sass 2.0.2` and `sass-rails 3.1.5` and it works just fine. It must be either some other gem or something you did playing around. Try creating a blank gemset and only reintalling the gems you need. Also, `sass-rails 3.2.3` is the default for use with `rails 3.2.3`.

Comment: I did try creating a new gemset with rvm but the project still uses the old one and I don't know how to force it to use this one. For me, when I install sass-rails without specifying the version I get 3.1.6 and a stack level too deep error on compile. How can I force my project to use the new gemset. And thanks for taking the trouble to try it out!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10609/discussion-between-paul-simpson-and-kakubei)

Answer (score 0):

Log the asset prefix in one of your controller actions:

```
Rails.logger.info [:asset_prefix, YourAppName::Application.instance.config.assets.prefix].inspect
```

then visit the action.

If you see that the path is anything except "/assets", something must have changed that path. I don't think bootstrap would do that; it's probably something else.

As a quick fix, add this to your config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.prefix = '/assets'
```

For clarity this should be added near `config.assets.enabled` .

This is mentioned on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, section 5.4 (Changing the assets path).

Are your other files in app/assets being found ok? I'd be surprised if the `/railsAdminApi` were only prepended for bootstrap icons. Look at the logs to see what urls are being used to retrieve them (or use the firebug Net panel).

Comment: All the other assets are being found ok in the assets folder. It's just the bootstrap assets. I will include this debug and see what it says. Thanks.